# Conversion of String Object to String Primitive in Javascript

Tags: javascript

A silly question I guess, how can we convert a String object in javascript to a String primitive ? 
Problem is I am having a map in which key is a String literal and it is not giving any result if I am passing a String object to it. Any way i can covert that string object to primitive to get the results from map ?

Comment: You should be having string objects in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`valueOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.3) method to extract the primitive value from a wrapper object:

```
var sObj = new String("foo");
var sPrim = sObj.valueOf();
```

Wrapper objects (`String`, `Boolean`, `Number`) in JavaScript have a [`[[PrimitiveValue]]` internal property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2), which holds the primitive value represented by the wrapper object:

> `[[PrimitiveValue]]`: Internal state information associated with this object. Of the standard built-in ECMAScript objects, only Boolean, Date, Number, and String objects implement [[PrimitiveValue]].

This primitive value is accessible via `valueOf`.